# How can I change the default action of C-a in screen to just a backtick `?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I tried something like

```
escape ^`
```

But that did not do it? I just want to change the default ctrl-a behavior.

Also, is it possible to bind each numeric key (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) to change those specific windows? So I can just be like:

```
`1 and go to window 1

`2 goes to 2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your .screenrc file

*escape ``*

After that you should be able to use a single <kbd>`</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

you can set the escape sequence to be just backtick with `` escape ` ``. If you do it when you invoke screen (with -e) you need to escape the backtick from the shell: "screen -e ``".

Once you've done that, backtick+1 to backtick+9 will jump between windows.